# Include custom metadata using storagage().bucket().file(fileName).save(file)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload a string using a cloud function. I am able to upload the string as a CSV successfully, but I can't find a way to include custom metadata.

I've tried everything that people have suggested online but nothing seems to give the desired result. Here is my current attempt:

```
const file = admin.storage().bucket().file(csvName);

return file.save(body, {
                gzip: true,
                contentType: 'text/csv',
                //Trying to insert this metadata.
                metadata: {
                  campaignId: doc.data().campaignId,
                  typeOfUpload: 'contacts'
                }
    })
```

Everything works as expected, except the custom metadata that I need. Your assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

This is how it is done:

```
const file = admin.storage().bucket().file(csvName);

return file.save(body, {
               metadata: {
                 contentType: 'text/csv',
                 gzip: true,
                 metadata: {
                   campaignId: doc.data().campaignId,
                   typeOfUpload: 'contacts'
                 }
               }
          })
```